# login_message not show WordPress 5.1.1

Tags: wordpress

After I upgraded WordPress to  WordPress 5.1.1, the message displayed in the login form does not show anymore, even the login message that is code in the functions.php doesn't

```
function custom_login_message() {
        $message = '<p class="message">Welcome, if you haven\'t already read our  please do so before you register.</p><br />';
        return $message;
    }
    add_filter('login_message', 'custom_login_message');
```

If someone knows the reason or how to solve this, please let me know, thanks

Comment: Just added this code to a fresh plugin and activated on a local sandbox installation of Wordpress 5.1.1 and I cannot reproduce - the message *does* appear. Additionally, [there haven't been any commits affecting the `login_message` filter functionality for some time now](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commits/master/wp-login.php) - at first glance, it doesn't make sense to blame this on the upgrade to 5.1.1.

Comment: A good way to see if a wordpress filter is running is to a "die" in it, or something else catastrophic / to confirm it is running.

Comment: There could be another filter rewriting the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this way:

```
function custom_login_message( $message ) {
        $message .= '<p class="message">Welcome, if you haven\'t already read our  please do so before you register.</p><br />';
        return $message;
    }

add_filter('login_message', 'custom_login_message');
```

Comment: I Tried this and got the same result